# App layout don't work properly on RTL phone languages

Tags: android

I built an app, It all looks fine on my english system galaxy s7.
On hebrew systems (right to left) everything is going bad..
I can't upload photos, my level is not high enough.

Please help me if you know how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Comment: I can't upload photos to show you the problem but generally, i got a relative layout inside it there is a radio group inside that group 2 buttons for male and female and the buttons just appear ON eachother not side by side (just one example)